# Details of secondary storage not being displayed

Tags: java, android

In Android 4.2.2, under packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.java, there is a check `final boolean showDetails = mVolume == null || mVolume.isPrimary();`. I do not read java very well. Does this line mean that for secondary storage, the variable will be set to false? It this preventing the Settings from displaying details of external SD card? How can I set the variable to true for external storage as well safely? Would `final boolean showDetails = mVolume == null` work? Will it set showDetails to true if mVolume is null? That would be dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking the patches from [Link1](https://github.com/crt60/packages_apps_Settings/commit/8b2940c92ac593f44337401b4737dd186fe24345) and [Link2](http://review.android.git.linaro.org/#/c/3649/1/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.java) Fixed the issue. Still I don't understand the way the original AOSP code initialize the variable.